Estimation of upper intervall bound theta for $X_1,\dots,X_n$ uniformly i.i.d. on $[0,\theta]$
I have $X_1,\dots , X_n \sim\text{unif}([0,\theta])$ i.i.d. and I want to compute the maximum likelihood estimator for this $\theta$
My Log-Likelihood-Function is:
$$L_x(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i) - n\cdot \log(\theta)$$
I cannot just take the derivative and set equal to zero so I have to think of other methods to find the maximum.
I observe that an additional restriction is that at least $$\theta \geq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}X_i$$ and that the function is decreasing for $\theta$ but tbh I do not know what to do now.
I think that the solution is already $$\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}X_i$$ but how to get there from this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

"I observe that an additional restriction is that at least $\theta ≥\max_{1≤i≤n}(X_i)$
and that the function is decreasing for $θ$" - isn't this enough to conclude?

The likelihood is given by
$$
L(\theta;x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac 1{\theta}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\theta]}(x_i)\right)=\frac{1}{\theta^{n}}\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{[0,\theta]}(x_i).
$$
Then we notice that $\mathbf{1}_{[0,\theta]}(x_i)$ is equal to one if and only if for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $0\leqslant x_i\leqslant\theta$, that is
$\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}x_i\geqslant 0$ and $\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}x_i\leqslant \theta$. As a consequence,
$$
L(\theta;x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{1}{\theta^{n}}\mathbf{1}_{\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}x_i\geqslant 0}\mathbf{1}_{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}x_i\leqslant \theta}.
$$
Drawing a picture of this function of $\theta$ shows that indeed, the maximum is reached at $\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}x_i$.

Thank you a lot. :)
